# How to fix my date problem

Tags: php

what i want is this the date variable which i insert and select back in my table to echo should display the correct date like today date is 2005-10-27 when i insert the variable date and select to echo it display this 2012-10-20 also my U_date field i choose date for the type lastly how can i make the date to look like this 10-June-2010 not like this 10-6-2010

```
<?
 $name= ($_POST['name']);
  $u_date = date ('h.m.Y');

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO user
  (name, u_date) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $u_date. "')

 $query1 = "SELECT * FROM user";
 $result1 = mysql_query ($query1) or die('query error');
 $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

 $d_user = $line[name];
 $d_date = $line[u_date];

 echo"$d_user<br>$d_date";
?>
```

Comment: It's really difficult to understand your question. Using punctuation and distinct sentences would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
date ('h.m.Y');
h = 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros
m = Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
Y = A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
```

Are you really wanting to combine hours with months and years?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
echo date('d-F-Y'); // 30-October-2010
echo date('Y-m-d'); // 2010-10-30
?>
```

See php manual for [date formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Re obtaining the output you desire:
You could try parsing `$line[u_date]` into a time value using the [time(...)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function, then calling the [date(...)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to output the time value in whatever format you desire.

$formatted_date = date('(format string here)', time($line[u_date]));

Answer (score 0):

or you can try different approach through database

> SELECT name, DATE_FORMAT(u_date,
>   '%d-%M-%Y') AS u_date from user;